# Light gives weird black spots in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting, shadows, scale

I have some objects with weird black spots in cycles render, in rendered view and in the final render. I realize that it has something to do with light because, when I go to the sun settings and desactivate "cast shadows", those spots also disappear. Someone recommended me to change shadow bias and shadow sampling but that is something that I can only find in eevee.

I also discovered that if I scale-up the objects, the shadows get tinner. But that's not a solution for me, the objects need to be at a specific size.

Also, I'm sorry but I can't share my blender file, I'm not allowed.

Blender 2.81

My computer:

CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 2700X 8-core

GPU: GeForce GTX 1660 SUPER

32gb RAM
[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks like either non-manifold geometry or possibly bad normals, or a duplicate geometry that is underneath the main one. Are your drivers up to date?

Comment: it's not a non-manifold geometry. It's also not normals or duplicate geometry. As for the drivers, It shouldn't be that, since this problem only occurs in this project. I think it really is something to do with light becuase, as I said, when I go to the sun settings and desactivate "cast shadows", those spots also disappear.

Comment: Hmm… maybe just rebuild the cactus from scratch? I know it’s last resort-ish, but I think it might be time.

Comment: It's not affecting just the cactus, it's affecting everything

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the material nodes?

Comment: the material node is just a normal principled BSDF where the only values that are changed are the roughness and base color